# load an image into struts2 tooltip

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

I am trying to show an image in a tooltip, but all i get is the plain text. 
Code :`<s:textfield label="cvv" name="cvv" tooltip="<img src='%{images}/cvv_34.gif'>" />`

When I hover on my tooltip image all I see is the text `<img src='xyz.com/cvv_34.gif'>`

I have tried jsTooltipEnabled and it doesn't help. I am able to open the image in a separate browser, so image path's, etc are all good.

Any help would be appretiated.

Comment: Check this link for some nice examples... http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Answer (score 0):

That is because the input is escaped and I think it is not good practice to reference an image there. If you like fancy Tooltips take a look at the jQuery and css frameworks you are maybe using.

- [jQuery Ui Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)
- [Bootstrap Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Answer (score 0):

This is not depends on struts, but I recommend qTip2.

http://qtip2.com/

With this you can show almost everything in a tooltip. Simple text, or a complete html enabled content. Also you can make this tooltip ajax enable too.